# basic problem in jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/nhmbA/

In above link you'll find my working code.
The issue is when you first click on `Select For` button, it'll show a list but again you click on the same button then the list should not be visible but its vice-versa.

I know, this is due to `blur` event applied to the list but I also want the list to be hidden when its clicked outside.

Help me to sort this minor issue..

Comment: Why not use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

Comment: @mplungjan: toggle is buggy in IE<9...

Comment: Seriously? I had no idea. In what way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code change

```
$('.tglrOptns').blur(function(){
    $(this).css('display', 'none').siblings('.optnTglr:first').removeClass('seltd');
});
```

to

```
$('body').click(function(e){

    $('.tglrOptns').css('display', 'none')
     .siblings('.optnTglr:first').removeClass('seltd');

});
```

and add this

```
$('.tglrOptns').click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jishnuap/nhmbA/5/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nhmbA/6/
I have edited html code little bit on your updated code..
Please, see the bug..

Answer (score 0):

hi if you change the on click function

to:
     $('.optnTglr').live('click', function(e){

this should help

Comment: it'll be the same as click and also its for applying click event to dynamically added elements... not for static

Answer (score 0):

I have added a close label, on clicking it closes the options div